# Locating elements with Selenium webdriver and Angular

Tags: angularjs, selenium

I have problem with locating object

I have

```
<div class="form-item-pair form-group left" field="SearchGroup.Network">
    <div class="form-label">
    <div class="form-value">
        <ng-transclude>
            <div class="ui-select-container ui-select-bootstrap dropdown ng-valid" ng-class="{open: $select.open}" ng-model="vm.criteria.networkName">
                <div class="ui-select-match" ng-class="{'btn-default-focus':$select.focus}" ng-disabled="$select.disabled" ng-hide="$select.open" placeholder="Select network...">
                    <span class="btn btn-default form-control ui-select-toggle" style="outline: 0;" ng-click="$select.activate()" ng-disabled="$select.disabled" aria-label="Select box activate" tabindex="-1">
```

I must click on last element `span`, how create path to last span, in code only `field="SearchGroup.Network"` is unique?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='btn btn-default form-control ui-select-toggle']")).click();
```

It does not work because it is not unique

Answer (score 3):

You should use a CSS selector. To make it unique, add some of the attributes present on the path:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(
  "[field='SearchGroup.Network'] [placeholder='Select network...'] span[aria-label='Select box activate']"
)).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-select-match']/span")).click();
```

or this one

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-select-match']/following::span[1]")).click;
```

Answer (score 0):

With XPath:

```
By query = By.Xpath("//div[@field='SearchGroup.Network']//span[@class='btn btn-default form-control ui-select-toggle']");
```

In case you dont't find is gerated throw:

```
NoSuchElementException
```